# How to update MySQL table using RMySQL package

Tags: r, rmysql

Instead of append or overwrite an entire table to database, is there any function in RMySQL that can update only part of the table? Because some of our data could be imcomplete someday, that I need to remain the old table and only replace the rows that has new data coming in, here is the function I wrote, but did not work, any help would be appreciated:

```
col.info <- "(id int, timestamp bigint, yyyy int, mm int, dd int, value double, 
PRIMARY KEY(id, timestamp, yyyy, mm, dd))"

Func <- function(con, tbl.name, dat.set, col.info) {
  if (dbExistsTable(con, tbl.name)) {  
  dbWriteTable(con, tbl.name, dat.set, row.names=F, append=T);  #what can I change the append for??

  } else { 
  dbSendQuery(con, paste("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS", tbl.name, col.info, sep=" ")); 
  dbWriteTable(con, tbl.name, dat.set, row.names=F, append=T);
  }
} 

Func(conn_table, "daily_update", df, col.info)
```

Comment: you can use dbSendQuery. You say it did not work,  but how ? what do you get as message? Second I would call the function something like dailyUpdate and not Func.

Comment: I just ran the code once more, and this time it worked!! But last time the entire table got duplicated, I'm new to database, so if the primary key was there, the table should not have duplicated rows, am I right? Thanks.

Comment: yes! a primary key is unique by data row.

Comment: Thank you, @agstudy, I'll run the data tomorrow and hope everything goes well, appreciate it.

Comment: Last time I just run the code above, but when I run the entire codes, the entire table got duplicated again, and I found the problem is the timestamp, which generates a new number each time, therefore, the rows became different, I tried to delete the timestamp in the Primary Key, but seems not help

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across the [dbx package](https://github.com/ankane/dbx) which does exactly what you need.

The following code will execute an upsert (on duplicate key update) query on your database table. Just replace the where_cols argument with whichever columns act as your primary key.

```
install.packages("dbx")
library(dbx)
dbx::dbxUpsert(con, tbl.name, dat.set, where_cols = c("id"))
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17995673)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @mmgross, I've adjusted my answer accordingly.